# Windows 10 Fastboot Driver

Tags: fastboot, windows, sony-xperia, 6.0-marshmallow, sony-xperia-z3-compact

My Sony Z3 Compact is currently unusable and I would like to flash the Marshmallow version of [FXP](http://fxpblog.co).

Unfortunately it seems like I can't find any `fastboot` (or as device manager calls it: `S1Boot Fastboot`) driver for Windows 10.

Am I looking somewhere wrong or is there simply no `fastboot` driver out there for Windows 10 yet?

Regards

Comment: Add your normal driver for Z3 Compat and then download fastboot files normally

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution myself: Windows 10 somehow does not want to install the driver, as it can not verify the manufacturer. So the driver from [Sony Developer's site](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/fastboot-driver/) works just fine.
After deactivating the Windows driver signature check everything works fine.

To deactivate proceed like this: (taken from [HERE](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_devices/how-do-i-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-win/a53ec7ca-bdd3-4f39-a3af-3bd92336d248?auth=1))

> 1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>
> 2. Once your Computer has rebooted you will need to choose the Troubleshoot option
> 3. Then head into Advanced options
> 4. Then Startup Settings
> 5. Since we are modifying boot time configuration settings, you will need to restart your computer one last time
> 6. Here you will be given a list of startup settings that you can change. The one we are looking for is “Disable driver signature
>      enforcement”. To choose the setting, you will need to press the F7 key

Comment: It is not needed to restore again (IMHO) as when installing a mismatching signature driver it will show a red window advicing it, so you will realize that something wrong is going there.

Comment: Here is a much easier way to install drivers manualy https://support.sonymobile.com/sa-en/xperiaxz/faq/wifi-&-connectivity/0231018805656b91c0145c620eeaf004cb9/

Answer (score 21):

By looking at the inf file, you can find that it tells to use the WinUSB driver. So there is a better solution than disabling driver signature enforcement, you can use the tool Zadig (http://zadig.akeo.ie/). This tools create a self-signed inf for this specific device, using ephemeral keys, added to the trusted certificate store (for this only device / inf), removing the need to disable signature check.

So you can do this :

1. Download the tool, start it.
2. Select the "S1Boot fastboot" device
3. Select the WinUSB Driver
4. Click Install

And then `fastboot devices` list your device.