# Windows 10 and fastboot driver | Nexus 5X

Tags: fastboot, windows, nexus-5x, nexus

I can not use fastboot on my pc with Windows 10 to flash something on my Nexus 5X.

I've installed Ubuntu and adb/fastbook works correctly.
With Ubuntu I've installed TWRP and SuperSU.

On Windows 10:
- Adb works.
- I've Android Studio with the latest platform-tools.
- I've tried with [15 seconds ADB Installer v1.4.3](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979).
- I've tried with [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129174/windows-10-fastboot-driver).
- I've already removed all usb-driver (as Nexus Root Toolkit suggest) and retry all.

What can I do?

Comment: What does device manager show while you boot in fastboot mode?

Comment: An "Android Bootloader Interface"

Comment: Did you try the drivers form the Android developer site? https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there are some 3rd party fastboot installers for Windows that might work in your scenario.  The XDA Developer's website had a few handy installers for Windows 10 fastboot you might want to check out.

[Fastboot and ADB Installer for Windows 10](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=48915118#post48915118)

Comment: I've already seen that topic (3° point - 15 seconds ADB Installer)

Comment: I see (again) the second video and, I don't know why, now it works. Thanks.